# How to calculate payment in google sheets based on the names of employees

Tags: google-chrome, google-sheets, sum, row, func

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GsJdo.jpg)

I want to how to calculate a person's salary based on their name so i dont have to scroll through the document and add each column 1 by one across that particular individual's name.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l4hWwoVBPSyxVbTdhuUN6uo1Jmx09BRbFV1Y_5dg_I4/edit?usp=drivesdk

Ive attached a sheet here

Answer (score 1):

It is almost always easier to provide help if you share a sheet with your data, [as described here](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/3808684?hl=en).  But you can try the following formula anywhere in your sheet:

```
=QUERY(C1:D,"
   select C, sum(D) 
   where C <> '' 
   group by C 
   order by C 
   label sum(D) 'Pay' ",1)
```

This assumes your data, with a header row, begins in C1, as shown in my image below.  Adjust the `QUERY` range , C1:D, to meet your requirements.

There are other ways to do this, so if this doesn't seem to help you, let us know, and please share a sample sheet.

[image]

Comment: everything seems to be good except the fact that it sometimes names the same person twice instead of combining all of their salaries in to 1. Ive attached a sheet above, you can check it

Comment: With the data in your sample sheet, I do not get any duplication of names.  I do see both "dawood" and "daeood" - that may be a typing mistake, with "daeood" on row 73 in column A.  But if you are seeing duplication of names, please show it in your sample sheet, so we can see it as well.  Your sample sheet did not include the formula I suggested for you.  If still having a problem, please share your sheet so that anyone can edit it, not just view it.  See guide here: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/138382/how-to-share-a-google-sheets-demo-spreadsheet/138383#138383